# Display related questions in a search-style manner

Tags: feature-request, related-questions

Given a question like [Is it possible to change the class of a Ruby object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7528552/is-it-possible-to-change-the-class-of-a-ruby-object), which has related questions including

- [Interface Contract, Class Object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/219425/interface-contract-class-object)
- [Variable variable class extensions in PHP--is it possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/304509/variable-variable-class-extensions-in-php-is-it-possible)
- ...
- [Initialize a Ruby class from an arbitrary hash, but only keys with matching accessors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1676200/listing-the-accessors-in-a-ruby-class)

I'd like to be able to display the related questions in a search-style manner. That is, see the title, then the start of the question, the tags, and the question's score.

Is this currently possible?

Comment: This would be great. Something like `inquestion:num related:1` or just `related:num`.